# WPF DataGrid editable GroupDescriptions

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

I just want make my DataGird group editable.
I use this code to set the group in .cs

```
ICollectionView oView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(oDatas.oLstImg);
oView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription(nameof(CDataScriptImg.sGrp)));
```

But the CollectionViewGroupInternal.Name was ReadOnly
I cannot set the TwoWay for directly edit the selected group name.

Any idea how to do that?

Thanks in advance
Eric.

Comment: What exactly do you want to edit? The name that is displayed in the view? You shouldn't (you cannot!) update the `CollectionViewGroupInternal.Name` property itself.

Comment: Yes I see that.
But I would like to see a TextBlock (TwoWay).
On set => that will update all elements of my list group : oDatas.oLstImg.sGrp

But Text block can only be associated with a single String.
How could I manage an ObservableCollection by my side ?